# Regex exclude another regex from a regex

Tags: regex, html-parsing, regexp-replace

I have this regex to find and replace `:` `;` `?` `!`

```
/(\u00AB|\u2014)(?:\s+)?|(?:\s+)?([\?!:;\u00BB])/g
```

but I'd like to ignore the characters within a style tag i.e `<a style='font-weight:bold'>`

Regex to ignore `(?!.style=\".*\")`
How do I accomplish that?

Comment: You really can't, because you can't tell with a regex if you're "in a style tag".

Comment: You _really_ don't want to use regexes to parse HTML.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Example to match `[:;?!]` outside angle brackets: [`[:;?!](?![^><]*>)`](https://regex101.com/r/sQQCbl/1) (explanation on right side).